# Old British Empire

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

> [image]
>
> **Across**
>   1. #1 in Waterloo: a famous Duke (10)
>   7. Material essential to hotel management (3)
>   8. In Cuba, three facing death for unauthorized entry (11)
>   9. Exotic free-diving spot (4)
>   10. About-faces in response to poetic forms (8)
>   13. Newcomer taking secret code of silence (6)
>   14. Cheapskate going in front of the back of queue, in opposition to usual rules (6)
>   16. Thorough detective's leaders followed around (8)
>   17. Greatest footballer named George (4)
>   20. Beast mixed in condiment put in place once more (11)
>   21. Help a spouse regularly (3, abbr.)
>   22. Gradually examine taking lead, eventually concluding after small-scale scholarship ends (4,2,4)
>
> **Down**
>   1. News about new father having lost his head for Irish city (9)
>   2. Song and French corset – devious tools for the police (3,9)
>   3. Militant group of two capturing member of parliament (4)
>   4. Board game's appeal regularly becoming doctrine (6)
>   5. In portfolio, evil organization backing Mediterranean product (5,3)
>   6. Burma (Myanmar) protecting woman chased by a young Ben Affleck (3)
>   7. Mr. Franklin with announcement after Fabergé produced these breakfast items (4,8)
>   11. Poor workplace from southwest consumes hopes of personnel's leaders (9)
>   12. Piercing tip of spear weapon held by Poseidon (8)
>   15. Assault of Arthur put off (4,2)
>   18. Submit to the authority of old British Empire's leaders, Yankee (4)
>   19. Result of burning tree (3)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solved grid:

> [image]

Clue explanations:

> [image]
>
>  The annotation might not make the last clue clear. "Gradually" is the definition, and then we have:
>  • *examine* **=** TEST
>  • *taking lead ...* **=** containing PB (the elemental abbreviation) and...
>  • *... eventually concluding* **=** Y, the conclusion of "eventually"
>  • *after small-* **=** everything so far comes after S
>  • *scale scholarship ends* **=** and finally, the ends of "scale scholarship"